# Not able to write in a file in /sys/

Tags: android, android-ndk, file-permissions, android-source

I am working on aosp, and trying to write in /sys/devices/platform/...somefile.

I am able to write in this file if my app has debugable=true, if I changed this to debugable=false. Then my application is getting `permission denied` error.

My app is a system app ,having system UID and signed with platform keys. I wanted to know that what extra permission android gives to app, when it is in debug mode.

Also, is the system app is write place to access files in /sys/device/.. or it should be handled from somewhere else.

code :

```
sprintf(szFileName,"/sys/devices/platform/../../somefile");
size_t nwritten = 0;
int fd = open(szFileName, O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
if(fd < 0){ // debug prints here permission denied }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Regards,
Yuvi

Comment: Try adding this to Android.mk : LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

Comment: @T-Chen thanks buddy but I guess it is added from kitkat, I am still working on gingerbread :)